# For which real values of $\alpha$ PDE $\Delta u(x,y)+2u(x,y)=x-\alpha$ has at least one weak solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

**Problem.** Consider boundary value problem:
\begin{cases}
\Delta u(x,y)+2u(x,y)=x-\alpha,  & \text{in $\Omega$,} \\
u(x,y)=0, & \text{on $\partial\Omega$,}  \\
\end{cases}
where $\alpha$ is real, $\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$  and $\Omega=(0,\pi)\times(0,\pi)$. The question is for which $\alpha$ we have at least one weak solution for this PDE.

Function $u$ is said to be weak solution to this problem iff $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and equation is satisfied in sence of distributions.

**Solution.** To solve this problem we should use [Fredholm alternitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative). For our case it takes the form (formally):

> $Lu=f$ has solution for all permissable $f$ that satisfies
>   $(f,v)_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int_\Omega fv\,dx=0$, where v is solution for
>   adjoint homogeneous equation $L^*v=0$.

Adjoint homogeneous equation has next form:

\begin{cases}
\Delta v(x,y)+2v(x,y)=0,  & \text{in $\Omega$,} \\
v(x,y)=0, & \text{on $\partial\Omega$,}  \\
\end{cases}

To solve it you can use method called separation of variables, on rectangle variables are separated very easy. You get $v(x,y)=C\,sinx\,siny$, where $C$ is arbitrary constant. We fix $C=1$.

Now we can easily find for which $f$ our main equation has at least one solution.

$$(f,v)_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int_\Omega fv\,dx=\int_\Omega(x-\alpha)sinx\,siny\,dx=2\pi-4\alpha=0 \text{ when } \alpha=\frac{Pi}{2}$$

Comment: What is $\Delta_{xy}$?

Comment: $\Delta_{xy}$ is Laplacian with respect to variables in subscript, in this case it is $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$. I edited question to avoid this symbol.

Comment: Please, edit your question and try to follow the instructions given in the box below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is essentially correct; just one small mistake (with the integral over $\Omega$). Hint:

> The integral over $\Omega$ equals $2 \pi - 4 \alpha$

Comment: Yes, you are right.